# How to config coredns with multi namespaces in kubernetes, to achive pods in each namespace gets it own dns resolution

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, coredns

Kubernetes version 1.13.5, installed by kubeadm, in bare metal.

I'v created 2 namespaces, which are 'dev' & 'test'. Add some self-created dns record(like 'mysql.a.com') into coredns which default in 'kube-system' ns.

What I want to achive is to have pods in each namespace got it own dns record resolution, like pod in 'dev' ns lookup for 'mysql.a.com' gets 1.1.1.1, pod in 'test' ns lookup for 'mysql.a.com' gets 2.2.2.2. And all these service I want to map a DNS record to, is outside of the cluster.

Is this possible? or there're something I miss.

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from configuring cluster wide defaults in CoreDNS for this. Instead use Kubernetes services.

The [service type ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) can be used to create an entry in DNS. Since ExternalName services, just like other services, are namespaced resources you can have the same DNS entry resolving differently in the respective namespace.

Example for dev:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: dev-database.example.com
```

Example for test:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: test-database.example.com
```

Inside each namespace, a DNS query for `database.svc.cluster.local` will resolve either to `dev-database.example.com` or `test-database.example.com`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've read the 'Type ExternalName' you gave me, it seems ExternalName could only be used inside the cluster(please point me out if I'm wrong, thx (ノ￣▽￣)). And in my architecture, the service I want to map a DNS record to, is outside of the cluster, is ExternalName still work in this situation? Sorry to have you misunderstand this, I'll update the question.

Comment: I indeed understood your question as services being inside the cluster. If that's not the case, then ExternalName won't help.

Comment: Right, is there any other way to achive this? Thank you